# What reference do I need to call UpdateModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, updatemodel

I am trying to use `UpdateModel` in a class other than my controller and it doesn't work.
When I call `UpdateModel` in my controller class it works perfectly. The references are the same in both classes.

Would someone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a reference issue.  Your controller inherits from `Controller` which has a virtual `UpdateModel` method.  This allows you to call the method in a derived class.  This method will only be available in other types that inherit from `Controller` and in instances of `Controller` itself.

Comment: its actually not virtual. least on RC1 it isn't! did it used to be? i really want it to be